Only 1 PWM pin working when controlling via sysfs
I’m using sysfs to control my rpi5’s pwm andI’m having an issue where only one of my pwm pins is outputting a value (The pin that is working is gpio 18/physical pin 12/pwm2). In the pinout.xyz page, it shows that physical pins 12/32/33/35 have built in hardware PWM. (Correct me if I’m wrong). I set up a circuit with 4 LEDs connected to physical pins 12, 32, 33 and 35, then I outputted values from all 4 pwm pins in the sysfs. Here are the commands I used:
Cd /sys/class/pwm/pwmchip2
Echo 0 > export
Cd pwm0
Echo 2000000 > period
Echo 1000000 > duty_cycle
Echo 1 > enable

I then did this with all the 3 pwm pins that weren't previously working by changing the export values but it wasn't for any of them.
I will add that I have already set up the pwm via config.txt, by adding in dtoverlay=pwm, but I’ve had this grudge where that might only be setting up the default pin (gpio 18/physical pin 12/pwm2) and therefore that is the only one that is working. I’ve found this resource which has information about the config.txt modules here: and this resource shows that I can use dtoverlay=pwm<pin>=<pinvalue> to set up an individual pin. But even when I did this, nothing changed.
I’m happy to provide more information about my specific circumstance if necessary, please ask and I will reply as soon as I can.
Do you guys have any idea on why the pins of 35,33 and 32 aren’t set up correctly or just malfunctioning?

Don't forget that you can also use software PWM. Compared to hardware PWM, the software PWM is slower and less stable - but it would work well enough for some applications; e.g. dimming a LED. What is your application?

@Seamus Right now I'm working on dimming an LED but soon I'll be doing more complicated programs. So I'd like to use hardware pwm.

Is one pwm enough - or do you need two?

@Seamus I've got one working already but a second one would be great.

OK - I think I've figured how to get two - but two is the max - there aren't any more hardware PWMs on a single Pi. My answer will be based on sysfs... hope that's OK - I just don't do Python. Maybe you can figure out how to translate it to Python.

@Seamus Great, yes I will translate it.

OK - just uploaded & made a quick edit. Let me know if you have questions.

First thing to know is that there are only two (2) hardware PWMs. So that's all you're ever going to get from a single RPi! Here's how to get both PWMs working on an RPi 5:
1. Edit your config.txt file & reboot:
$ sudo nano /boot/firmware/config.txt 
#
# Once the file is open, REMOVE 'dtoverlay=pwm' if it's in there, and add one line: 

dtoverlay=pwm-2chan

# save & close config.txt, and then reboot: 

$ sudo reboot 
...

2. After your system has finished booting:
# verify the overlay is loaded: 

$ ls /sys/class/pwm
pwmchip0  pwmchip2  pwmchip6 

# Pi 5 PWM is on pwmchip2 - so: 

$ cd /sys/class/pwm/pwmchip2

$ echo 2 > export && echo 3 > export 

$ ls 
device  export  npwm  power  pwm2  pwm3  subsystem  uevent  unexport 
#                            ^^^^  ^^^^
# NOTE creation of folders 'pwm2' & 'pwm3'. 

$ cd /sys/class/pwm/pwmchip2/pwm2

$ echo 2000000 > period && echo 1000000 > duty_cycle && echo 1 > enable 
#
# you should have a PWM pulse train on GPIO 18 (header pin 12) now.

$ cd /sys/class/pwm/pwmchip2/pwm3

$ echo 1000000 > period && echo 500000 > duty_cycle && echo 1 > enable 
#
# you should have a PWM pulse train on GPIO 19 (header pin 35) now.
# with the above settings, both PWM waveforms are 50% duty cycle,
# and the frequency of pwm3 (GPIO 19) is twice that of pwm2 (GPIO18).

Following are the o'scope traces made of the PWM waveforms; GPIO18 is on top, GPIO19 on bottom.

If it helps, here's a bash script that does the setup (except adding the overlay to config.txt):
#!/bin/bash

cd /sys/class/pwm/pwmchip2
echo 2 > export
sleep 1
echo 3 > export

cd /sys/class/pwm/pwmchip2/pwm2
echo 2000000 > period && echo 1000000 > duty_cycle && echo 1 > enable 

cd /sys/class/pwm/pwmchip2/pwm3
echo 1000000 > period && echo 500000 > duty_cycle && echo 1 > enable

From your $HOME directory (/home/pi or whatever):

save the file in your home directory as: pwm_script.sh

make it executable: chmod 755 pwm_script.sh

run it: ./pwm_script.sh



NOTES:

See this other answer on how to configure a single channel hardware PWM.


It worked! Is there any logic behind why it worked? Thank you very much for your help!!

Alright, thanks!
